# Uniform convergence of $f_n (x)=x^{2} - \frac{x}{n}$ on $[0, 1]$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I need help with this problem:
Consider the sequences of functions $(f_n)$ defined by: $$f_n (x)=x^{2} - \frac{x}{n}$$.

- Show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on$[0, 1]$.

I've already found the pointwise limit, which is $x^{2}$. How do I prove that it converges uniformly?

I tried by saying that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists an natural number $N$ such that $|f_n (x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, sí I ended up with $|x^{2} - \frac{x}{n} - x^{2}| = |\frac{x}{n}|$, I think that it is less that $\frac{1}{n}$ because $x$  is in the interval $[0, 1]$, $\frac{x}{n} < \epsilon$, so it converges uniformly to $f$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sup_{ x \in [0,1]} \mid f(x) - f_n(x) \mid \leq \frac{1}{n} \to 0$$

Thus the sequence converges uniformly

Comment: So $\frac{1}{n}$ is the supremum of  $f_n (x)$ on that interval? And as $n\to\infty$, $\frac {1}{n} \to 0$?

Comment: @davidllerenav Yep, it’s the supremum of $\mif f_n(x) -f(x) \mid$ not just $f_n(x)$

Comment: I see. The way we solved it is the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the $M$-test. It is just a straight-forward calculation using the definition of uniform convergence.